# How to get specified row from PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

So I have an array and form with input where I put an ID that should show the corresponding row from the array.

So far I have made this:

```
<?php
$file = 'people.txt';
$people = array();
    $ref = fopen($file, 'r');
    while ($row = fgets($ref, 1024)) {
        $row = explode("|", $row);
        $id = $row[0];
        $name = $row[1];
        $status = $row[2];
        $people[$id] = array('name' => $name, 'status' => $status);
    }
fclose($ref);

foreach($people as $id => $person) {
    if($_GET[person]==$id && $person[status]==1) {
        echo $person[name] . "(" . $id . "): ready";
    }
    if($_GET[person]==$id && $person[status]==0) {
        echo $person[name] . "(" . $id . "): not ready";
    }
    if($_GET[person]!=$id) {
        echo "Person with this ID was not found";
    }
}
?>
```

This shows the correct info of searched ID, but it also shows "person was not found" to every other person in the array. How can I get it to show only the person that matches the input?

Comment: Note, unless you have specifically defined `status` and `name`  as constants, you will get a lot of php warnings. Better to use quotes e.g. `$person["status"]`

Comment: Grabacr, could you please provide an update as to where your question stands? Were you able to use one of these answers to help solve your problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need AT ALL for the loop. If you already have the ID of the person, then there's no need to scan the array for that id, just use it directly:

```
if (isset($people[$id])) {
   ... do stuff with person # $id
} else {
   ... person does not exist
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are only searching for one "person ID", you do not need the second foreach loop in your code. I recommend refactoring a bit to include more error checking and also reading about [type juggling and casting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) in PHP.

I've modified your code to include some hints that should point you in the right direction:

```
<?php

$file = 'people.txt';
$people = array();

$ref = fopen($file, 'r');

while ($row = fgets($ref, 1024)) {
    $row = explode('|', $row);

    if (!isset($row[0]) || !isset($row[1]) || !isset($row[2])) {
        continue;
    }

    $id = (int) $row[0];
    $name = (string) $row[1];
    $status = (int) $row[2];

    $people[$id] = array('name' => $name, 'status' => $status);
}

fclose($ref);

$id = array_key_exists('person', $_GET) ? $_GET['person'] : null;

if (array_key_exists($id, $people)) {
    $person = $people[$id];

    if ($person['status'] === 1) {
        echo $person['name'] . ' (' . $id . '): ready';
    } else {
        echo $person['name'] . ' (' . $id . '): not ready';
    }
} else {
    echo 'Person with ID ' . htmlspecialchars($id) . ' not found';
}
```

If you plan on people.txt becoming large in size, consider storing the data in a database such as MySQL. This will eliminate having to read the contents of the file into memory on every request.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you need the array of all the people for some other purpose after this code, you can get only the person indicated by `$_GET['person']` from the file. Just add a check inside the while loop.

```
$person = null;     // initialize person

$ref = fopen($file, 'r');
while ($row = fgets($ref, 1024)) {
    $row = explode("|", $row);
    if ($row[0] == $_GET['person']) {    // only get rows that match the searched id
        $person = array('name' => $row[1], 'status' => $row[2]);
    }
}
fclose($ref);
```

This will reduce the memory usage of your script by avoiding creating an array of the entire file. The benefit of this obviously depends on the size of the file.

(Even if you *do* need the entire array, you can still set `$person` in an `if` block in your while loop at the same time you are filling the `$people` array.)

Then after that loop, `$person` will be just *one thing*: either an array with the last matched row in your file, or `null`. That means you won't have to find it in an array; you can output the status information like this:

```
if ($person) {
    echo "$person[name] ($person_id): ";
    echo $person['status'] ? 'ready' : 'not ready';
} else {
    echo "Person with this ID was not found";
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Use a boolean variable to detect if the person you're searching for is found or not, The code could be like this:

```
$found = false;
foreach($people as $id => $person) {
    if($_GET[person]==$id) {
        $found = true;
        if($person[status]==1)
            echo $person[name] . "(" . $id . "): ready";
        else if($person[status]==0) 
            echo $person[name] . "(" . $id . "): not ready";
        //You can (break;) here if you're sure that the $id is identical
    }
}
if($found == false)
    echo "Person with this ID was not found";
```